# Initialization of dependent form controls in FormGroup

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

There's a form group where some form control values depend on other form control values. In my particular case they are also mutually dependent, but this is not shown in the example below for simplicity.

Here's a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/CnHwMZZSvWo0EmfEmsyo?p=preview).

```
const fetchedFormValues = {
  timestamp: '1504116487374'
};

Observable.from(this.form.get('timestamp').valueChanges)
.filter(v => v)
.distinctUntilChanged()
.subscribe(timestamp => {
  console.log('timestamp', timestamp);
  this.form.get('date').setValue(new Date(timestamp).toISOString().substr(0, 10));
  this.form.get('time').setValue(new Date(timestamp).toISOString().substr(11, 12))
});

this.form.reset(fetchedFormValues);
```

Initial form values are fetched from the backend and being set with `reset` (this can also be done later on). The problem is that `setValue` for `date` and `time` works ok when `timestamp` is changed but is ignored on reset.

I'm trying to keep it as DRY as possible and avoid `this.form.get('date').setValue...` in multiple places because this is already done in listed observable.

Why are `date` and `time` form controls not affected by `timestamp` subscription on `reset`? Can `reset` behaviour be fixed to accept changes that are done by `setValue` there? Is there any other approach to handling (mutually) dependent form controls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FormGroup's `reset()` function looks like:

```
FormGroup.prototype.reset = function (value, options) {
    if (value === void 0) { value = {}; }
    if (options === void 0) { options = {}; }
    this._forEachChild(function (control, name) {
        control.reset(value[name], { onlySelf: true, emitEvent: options.emitEvent });
    });
    this.updateValueAndValidity(options);
    this._updatePristine(options);
    this._updateTouched(options);
};
```

in your case `this._forEachChild` will return controls in order:

1. timestamp
2. date
3. time

when timestamp field is set, its `valueChanges` is triggered and other two fields populated properly, but then those two fields are set to `undefined` (`value[name]`) again by `this._forEachChild` iterations.

so, the quickest fix would be to change order of your fields to:

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
  date: null,
  time: null,
  timestamp: null
});
```

this way `date` and `time` fields will be set to `undefined` and then in the last iteration 'timestamp' field will be filled and change values for `date` and `time` fields.

Another (preferred by me) solution would be to use `patchValue` function, instead of `reset`. `patchValue` function looks like:

```
FormGroup.prototype.patchValue = function (value, options) {
    var _this = this;
    if (options === void 0) { options = {}; }
    Object.keys(value).forEach(function (name) {
        if (_this.controls[name]) {
            _this.controls[name].patchValue(value[name], { onlySelf: true, emitEvent: options.emitEvent });
        }
    });
    this.updateValueAndValidity(options);
};
```

it iterates only over fields provided to the function, and not over controls. Thus, in your case only `timestamp` field will be updated and trigger its `valueChanges` event emitter.

so instead of

```
this.form.reset(fetchedFormValues);
```

write

```
this.form.patchValue(fetchedFormValues);
```

with `patchValue` you can also control triggering of `valueChanges` emitter. If you DO NOT WANT `valueChanges` to be triggered (which is not your case), you can write:

```
this.form.patchValue(fetchedFormValues, {emitEvent: false});
```

reference code source: https://unpkg.com/@angular/forms@4.3.6/bundles/forms.umd.js

Comment: Thanks, that;s great explanation, efficient yet simple. It never came to mind that order could matter here. I wonder if it's by design, considering the fact that object props are unordered (although de facto they are). Sadly, patchValue isn't interchangeable with reset, that was the first thing I've tried (it chokes on form arrays, for starters).